# how to get id of specific button and toggle it in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, togglebutton, jquery

i have a function in JavaScript that run some code when the activation button is clicked
this function toggle (change)
     
to
     
but i want this code to be more specific
i want to send id to this function and toggle only that object

for example i do this:
     
but i can't get id of that link in function

also you can see my code below:

this is my javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('a.activation').click(function(){
            var de_id = $(this).attr('de_id');
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.post('insert.php', {de_id:de_id});
            $('a.activation').toggle();
        });

        $('a.activation').click(function(){
            $('a.activation').toggle();
            var act_id = $(this).attr('act_id');
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.post('insert.php', {act_id:act_id});
            $('a.activation').toggle();
        });
    });

</script>
```

and this is the body:

```
<td><?php if($news['ns_act']==1){
                        echo "<a class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(0);\" de_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display: inline-block;\" ><img src=\"images\icons\activate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\"  /></a>
                              <a class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(1);\" act_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display:none;\" ><img src=\"images\icons\deactivate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\" /></a>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<a class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(1);\" act_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display: inline-block;\" ><img src=\"images\icons\deactivate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\"  /></a>
                          <a class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(0);\" de_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display:none;\"><img src=\"images\icons\activate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\" /></a>";
                }

                 ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('a.activation').click(function(e){
            var de_id = $(this).attr('de_id');
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.post('insert.php', {de_id:de_id});
            $("#"+e.target.id).toggle();
        });

        $('a.activation').click(function(e){
            $('a.activation').toggle();
            var act_id = $(this).attr('act_id');
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.post('insert.php', {act_id:act_id});
            $("#"+e.target.id).toggle();
        });
    });

</script>
```

html

```
echo "<a id='someid' class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(0);\" de_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display: inline-block;\" ><img src=\"images\icons\activate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\"  /></a>
<a id='someotherid' class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(1);\" act_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display:none;\" ><img src=\"images\icons\deactivate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\" /></a>";
```

Comment: can you give me some hint? e.target.id??
what should i do in my code?

Comment: You need to add id fields to the links in your html that you echo out

Comment: i tried this but in my js function i cant see anything!
i have tried to show content of e.target with alert() but it's return nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('document').ready(function(){
            switch=0;
            $('a.activation').click(function(){
               if(switch==0){
                   var de_id = $(this).attr('de_id');
                   var parent = $(this).parent();
                   $.post('insert.php', {de_id:de_id});
                   switch=1;
                   $(this).css("background","green").html('Activate');
                   }
              else{
                     var act_id = $(this).attr('act_id');
                     var parent = $(this).parent();
                     $.post('insert.php', {act_id:act_id});
                     switch=0;
                     $(this).css("background","red").html('Deactivate');
                  } 
            });

    });// ready end

</script>
```

html

```
<a class='activation' onClick=\"reply_click(this.{$news['ns_id']})\" href=\"javascript:return(0);\"act_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" de_id=\"{$news['ns_id']}\" style=\"display: inline-block;\" ><img src=\"images\icons\activate.png\" height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\"  /></a>
```

Comment: `$(this).css("background","red").html('Deactivate');` instead of this you can change `image` source

Comment: thanks you are correct my structure but real problem is about ID of clicked button!

Comment: can you explain where you using ID??

Comment: i have toggle link between activation and deactivation
i should have something like this:
ex: toogle a.activation12
i dont know javascript too much but if you work with publish and unpublish in joomla article manager you can understand what i mean

in my program right now when you click on one activation link all activation link is toggled
is it enough ?

Comment: yes
all id's come from database and i have change activation value in database
all my php program work right and i am sure about that
but i need to make this javascript function correct!?